# Can I control PF M-motor with PF train controller?

Tags: power-functions, remote-control

Can I control Power Functions M-motor from 8293 set with remote control from 60051 train set? It seems from the picture, that the sockets fit into each other. So if I have the train set, and want to build a remote controlled car, should I buy the 8293?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I control Power Functions M-motor from 8293 set with remote control from 60051 train set? It seems from the picture, that the sockets fit into each other.

Yes, you can control [any motor from Power Functions line](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=power%20functions%20motor#T=S) with [IR Speed Remote Control Unit](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64227c01&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) found in 60051 set.

> So if I have the train set, and want to build a remote controlled car, should I buy the 8293?

It depends. [8293 set contains](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8293-1) single [M-motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58120c01&idColor=86#T=C&C=86), which you can only use to drive back-forward or turn the wheels. You would need two sets at least to have a driving and steering model. It also depends how big of a vehicle you have as M-motors aren't very powerful and you might want to look into [L-motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99499c01#T=C) or [XL-motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58121c01).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I ended up with ordering set 42095, that is double price of 8293, so it worths it better then ordering two motor set.